# Customize package between book/article classes

Tags: tcolorbox, counters, package-writing, package-options

I wrote a small package that I used to typeset a book. Now, I'd like to reuse it for smaller documents. The package uses `tcolorbox` and defines a box like this:

```latex
\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={Lis.}{Lis.},
               ...
```

The only thing I need to change when writing shorter documents is to remove the line `number within=chapter`.

I'm not sure how to achieve that.  What's the best way:

- Use an `if` to somehow test if counter `chapter` is defined?
- Use an `if` to somehow test the document class (e.g., `book` vs `article`)?
- Add an option to the package and test it to include/exclude `number within`?

I have very little experience developing packages, and I'll welcome any help on this question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

you can check for document class, by name but more general is to check for `\chapter`

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {no chapter version}
   {chapter version}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still stuck. At this point, this is more a tcolorbox/pgfkeys question. I tried "number within=\@ifundefined{chapter}{???}{chapter}," but I don't know what to use for ??? to leave the key unset. I also tried to rely on tcbset, but "\tcbset{new/number within=chapter}" doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: maybe ask a new question about that I haven't used tcolorbox keys too much myself. @MichelCharpentier

Comment: Just did. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664528/.  Thanks.