# Conditionally set "number within" in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys

I've defined a `tcolorbox` listing as follows:

```latex
\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={Lis.}{Lis.},
               ...
```

It works fine in books, but I need to turn off `number within` in smaller documents. I've tried these approaches:

- `\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{number within=chapter},}` but that confuses `pgfkeys`.
- `number within=\@ifundefined{chapter}{???}{chapter},` but I don't know what to use for `???` so the key remains unset (I tried `\pgfkeysnovalue`, but no luck).
- `\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{\tcbset{new/number within=chapter}}` but this doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever.

What's the right approach for what I'm trying to do?

Here's a code example. It would work if the document is a book, but not an article. The goal is to somehow use `\@ifundefined{chapter}` somewhere to disable the `number within` setting when there are no chapters:

```latex
\documentclass{article} % works when book
\usepackage{tcolorbox,cleveref}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,
               number within=chapter,
               crefname={Lis.}{Lis.},
               Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
               list inside=lis
              ]{code}[1][]{%
              comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #1},
              listing and comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[bar]
foo
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Edited to add (non-working) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new and general utility key `/utils/ifundefined={<csname>}{<options if true>}{<options otherwise>}`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,cleveref}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /utils/ifundefined/.code n args={3}{%
    \@ifundefined{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\newtcblisting[
  auto counter,
  /utils/ifundefined={chapter}{}{number within=chapter},
  crefname={Lis.}{Lis.},
  Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
  list inside=lis
]{code}[1][]{
  comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #1},
  listing and comment
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\begin{code}[bar]
foo
\end{code}

\begin{code}[bar]
foo
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With document class `report` instead of `article`:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Define a suitable style for the `new` family of keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,cleveref}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,listings,breakable}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  new/.cd,
  number within highest/.estyle={
    number within = \@ifundefined{chapter}{section}{chapter}
  }
}

\newtcblisting[
  auto counter,
  number within highest,
  crefname={Lis.}{Lis.},
  Crefname={Listing}{Listings},
  list inside=lis
]{code}[1][]{
  comment={Listing~\thetcbcounter: #1},
  listing and comment
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{code}[bar]
foo
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When chapter is undefined, I don't want listings numbered by sections. Rather, I want them numbered globally, i.e., without any "number within" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer as a starting point, I came up with this:

```latex
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\tcbset{new/.cd,number within if chapter/.style={}}}{
\tcbset{new/.cd,number within if chapter/.style={number within = chapter}}}
```

I still feel this could be simplified, but at least it seems to work for now.